# Order of Layout and Open

Tags: java, layout, dialog, swt

**Is there significance to the order of calling shell.open() and shell.layout() when opening an SWT Dialog?**

Using the Eclipse editor plugins, default code for `Dialog` classes can be **automatically generated** for you.  The **default code** for the open() method looks like this:

```
/**
 * Open the dialog.
 * @return the result
 */
public Object open() {
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this code, open() occurs first, followed by layout() second.  My expectation is that one would actually want to layout the shell first before opening.

```
...
    shell.layout();
    shell.open();
...
```

My assumption that drawing will occur once open() is called, and is therefore inefficient and unnecessary as the screen would be drawing the shell as it is rearranged.  Aside from this theoretical issue of efficiency, however, there is no obvious difference between doing these two things in either order.

**Is the default that is given correct, or should it be changed?  Is there a benefit to doing so?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing is not done in the `open()` call, this will just add a paint event to the list of pending events.

The queued paint event will be processed in the display `readAndDispatch()` call loop.

So it does not matter which order the `open` and `layout` are done as both calls are before the `readAndDispatch` call.